# How to fix infinite dialog loop on closing, when handling a authentication request with CefSharp

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, cefsharp

So the application I'm making needs to handle authentication request sent by the webpage in order to log in and use that page. To achieve this, I found after some research that I should implement the IRequestHandler interface of CefSharp and use it method called "GetAuthCredentials" to open a dialog and request the username and password from here.

This all seems to work fine and I am able to login to the page with the correct credentials. However when I try to close my entire application after logging into a website via this method, the application freezes and refuses to close after that. It does seem to close the browser control on the form but not the form itself.

I can close the application normally without any issues when I do not have to use the log in, but whenever I do the scenario above happens and I'm unable to close it except for ending the task within Taskmanager.

I suspect the "GetAuthCredentials" is never truly handled or it keeps requesting the dialog over and over again, resulting in an infinite loop that keeps my application from closing. However I have not been able to find the root of this problem.

**The Requesthandler implementation with "GetAuthCredentials":**

```
class RequestEventHandler : IRequestHandler
    {

        bool IRequestHandler.GetAuthCredentials(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, bool isProxy, string host, int port, string realm, string scheme, IAuthCallback callback)
        {
            bool handled = false;

            AuthenticationDialog dlg = new AuthenticationDialog(host);

            dlg.ShowDialog();

            if (dlg.DialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                callback.Continue(dlg.UserName, dlg.Password);
                handled = true;
            }

            return handled;
        }
```

**The Dialogform it opens:**

```
 public partial class AuthenticationDialog : Form
    {
        internal string UserName { get; set; }
        internal string Password { get; set; }

        public AuthenticationDialog(string Hostname)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Lbl_WebUrl.Text = Hostname;

        }

        private void Btn_SignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(Tbx_Username.TextLength > 0 && Tbx_Password.TextLength > 0)
            {
                UserName = Tbx_Username.Text;
                Password = Tbx_Password.Text;
            }
            else if (Tbx_Username.TextLength == 0 && Tbx_Password.TextLength > 0)
            {
                Lbl_Error.Text = SetError(1);
            }
            else if (Tbx_Username.TextLength > 0 && Tbx_Password.TextLength == 0)
            {
                Lbl_Error.Text = SetError(2);
            }
            else
            {
                Lbl_Error.Text = SetError(0);
            }
        }
```

The sign-in button here has it's Dialog_Result property set to Dialogresult.OK

**The Method that closes the application: (Located in the mainform that contains the browser)**

```
private void btn_ApplicationClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            browser.Dispose();
            Cef.Shutdown();
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

Any suggestion or fix for this problem would be much appreciated, this problem has been grinding my gears for a couple of days now.

**Update:** 
With the advice of @amaitland I've opened the dialog on the UI thread using the code below:

```
bool IRequestHandler.GetAuthCredentials(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, bool isProxy, string host, int port, string realm, string scheme, IAuthCallback callback)
        {
            bool handled = false;

            ChromiumWebBrowser b = browserControl as ChromiumWebBrowser;
            b.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                AuthenticationDialog dlg = new AuthenticationDialog(host);
                dlg.ShowDialog();

                if (dlg.DialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    callback.Continue(dlg.UserName, dlg.Password);
                    handled = true;
                }
            });

            return handled;
```

This seems to work and let's my application close when it has used a log-in, however now it seems to be unable to process the login information. When logging in, it closes the dialog and doesn't seem to do anything with the credentials I've given it.

Did I miss something or is my implementation wrong?

Comment: You need to open the dialog on the UI thread.

Comment: @amaitland could you explain how I should do that? I'm fairly new to CefSharp and haven't found this option myself yet.

Comment: Using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke?view=netframework-4.7.2 You can cast `IWebBrowser` to `ChromiumWebBrowser` or `Control` to access `BeginInvoke`

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, update your original issue and show the full code.

Comment: @amaitland sorry, not really used to stackoverflow yet. I've updated my original question with my new problem, instead of asking it here.

Comment: You effectively always return false. You need to return true, use http://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IAuthCallback_Cancel.htm to cancel

Answer (score 0):

So with some helpfull suggestions of @amaitland, I've been able to fix my issue, resulting in the code below for the `GetAuthCredentials` method of the RequestHandler.

```
bool IRequestHandler.GetAuthCredentials(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, bool isProxy, string host, int port, string realm, string scheme, IAuthCallback callback)
        {
            ChromiumWebBrowser b = browserControl as ChromiumWebBrowser; //casts the given browsercontrol as chromiumwebbrowser, to acces the .beginInvoke method
            b.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                //creates an instance of the authentication dialog to get the user credentials
                AuthenticationDialog dlg = new AuthenticationDialog(host);
                dlg.ShowDialog();


                if (dlg.DialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)  //if the sign-in button is clicked
                {
                    callback.Continue(dlg.UserName, dlg.Password);
                }
                else // if the close or cancel button on field is clicked
                {
                    callback.Cancel();
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
```

Here I opened the dialog on the UI thread instead of the main thread with `.BeginInvoke()` and made sure the request would pas as handled when used 
This fixes all of the issues I had with it, and it might give an example to implement your own RequestHandler for `GetAuthCredentials`.

Comment: `CEF/Chromium` uses many threads, in this case you were attempting to perform `UI` operations on the `IO` thread. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#threads